Visual Studio 2022 httpfile localDatetime is sending UTC time
I am building a web API that should be able to receive POST requests containing user messages. I have a .http file that should send a request to test this interface. One of the fields that it should send is the current date/time expressed als local time and formatted as yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.
Below is my .http file:
@HostAddress = http://localhost:527

@NowUtc = {{$datetime "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"}}
@NowLocal = {{$localDatetime "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"}} 

POST {{HostAddress}}/api/Message
Content-Type: application/json

[
{
  "username": "myusername",
  "message": {
    "id": 12345678,
    "date": "{{NowLocal}}",
    "content": "Some message text"
  }
}
]

No matter whether I send {{NowLocal}} or {{NowUtc}} as the date field, the value that is delivered in the POST request is always UTC. My system's local time is CEST, so I expect that the time would be UTC+2, but as said it isn't. I also tried to format the datetime as iso8601 but that makes no difference: NowUtc and NowLocal contain the same value. Omitting the quotation marks around the date field in the message body results in a validation error and no POST request is sent at all.
If I set @NowLocal = {{$localDatetime "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" +2 h}} I get the correct local time, but of course that should not be necessary. It only proves that the localDatetime variable contains UTC.
Am I missing something obvious?

Since you don't mention any issue of your system time settings, it is usually a tool issue. Different tools has different default time settings. I tried this with VS Code and REST Client installed. When I hang my mouse on "{{NowLocal}}" I can see the time is localtime. And I received the correct result. You could try different tools to verify if it is the tool issue.

What datatype are you using for date ?
if you use DateTime, should post using local time, if using DateTimeOffset will be UTC. that is what I found.
Using DateTime

Using DateTimeOffset


All fields except for id (at least in the simplified example) are strings. Id is an int. This raises the question: could it be possible that datetimes formatted as string are always expressed as UTC? And that it's the receiver's responsibility to convert them to local time? I will try what happens if I change the receiving data object. The problem here however is that this is a connection to an external web service which definitely sends the time as string, and I cannot change that. Nevertheless, I will change the datatype for a test. I want to understand what is going on. Thanks so far.
